# ЧПУ - обрабатываем части URL, как GET переменные

Tags: php, apache, url, get, mod-rewrite

Сейчас работает:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?a=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?a=$1
```

Как добавить второй GET чтобы было sitename.ru/part/page
только если это вторая страница и более, part в url это а.

---

*Поиском пользовался. Если есть где то хорошо написано, тыкните носом.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)[/]?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2
```